# Using "material-components-web" within "react-boilerplate" code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, single-page-application, react-boilerplate

After some research on the existing boilerplate code on GitHub, I've decided to use [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate) to get started with my React application. I was planning on adding the Material styles on my website, and since the [react-mdl](https://github.com/react-mdl/react-mdl) is deprecated now, I was planning on using the [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) dependency on my project.

This is my first React application, and I'd like to know a clean way to remove the default styles and add dependency to material-components-web on my project.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Updated Answer (v0.22.0)**

For setting up the CSS you can still use the plain css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LINK_TO/material-components-web.css">
```

But I would recommend using scss, this way you can override different values like theme colors and customize everything the way you want. Example:

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #404040;
$mdc-theme-accent: #a349a3;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;  

@import "@material/ripple/mdc-ripple";
@import "@material/typography/mdc-typography";
@import "@material/theme/mdc-theme";
@import "@material/button/mdc-button";
```

For using components that need logic in terms of javascript I usually write react.js wrapper for this component. Here is an example for an accept/decline dialog component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDCDialog } from '@material/dialog/dist/mdc.dialog';

class AcceptDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.passThroughInfo;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.dialog = new MDCDialog(this.refs.dialog);
        // provide control to parent component to open the dialog from there
        this.props.provideCtrl({
            show: (passThroughInfo) => {
                this.passThroughInfo = passThroughInfo;
                this.dialog.show();
            },
            close: () => {
                this.passThroughInfo = undefined;
                this.dialog.close();
            }
        });

        this.dialog.listen('MDCDialog:accept', () => {
            this.props.acceptCb(this.passThroughInfo);
        })

        this.dialog.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', () => {
            this.props.declineCb(this.passThroughInfo);
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.provideCtrl(null);
    }

    defaultProps = {
        className: "",
        id: "",
        header: "",
        text: "",
        acceptCb: function () { },
        declineCb: function () { }
    }

    render() {
        let className = "mdc-dialog accept_dialog" + this.props.className;
        return (
            <aside className={className} role="alertdialog" ref="dialog" id={this.props.id}>
                <div className="mdc-dialog__surface">
                    {this.props.header !== "" &&
                        <header className="mdc-dialog__header">
                            <h2 className="mdc-dialog__header__title">
                                {this.props.header}
                            </h2>
                        </header>
                    }
                    <section className="mdc-dialog__body">
                        {this.props.section}
                    </section>
                    <footer className="mdc-dialog__footer">
                        <button type="button" className="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Decline</button>
                        <button type="button" className="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept">Accept</button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
                <div className="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
            </aside>
        );
    }
}

export default AcceptDialog
```

Then use like this in other components:

```
// How to open the accept dialog
this.accept_dialog.show(data);

// The callback called on accept
callback(data){...}

<AcceptDialog 
    acceptCb={this.callback}
    provideCtrl={ctrl => this.accept_dialog = ctrl}>
</AcceptDialog>
```

---

**____________OLD ANSWER_______________**

**1) Adding CSS**

That is reather easy. You can just add it to your index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LINK_TO/material-components-web.css">
```

If you are using SASS you can also access the sass files (you have to install the @material npm module: npm install --save @material). Then you need node-sass and include the path to the @material folder in your webpack config. I have not tried this out but in theory, that should work.

---

**2) Adding Javascript**

Again you have more possibilities. Here is what I have done. You can import mdc like this

```
class Foo extends Component(){
componentDidMount(){
    // either this like that
    mdc.textfield.MDCTextfield.attachTo(this.refs.textfield);
    // or like that
    const MDCTextfield = mdc.textfield.MDCTextfield;
    const textfield = new MDCTextfield(this.refs.textfield);
}
render() {
    return(
        <form className="form-group" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
            <div className="mdc-textfield" ref="textfield">
                <input type="text" id="my-textfield" className="mdc-textfield__input"/>
                <label className="mdc-textfield__label" htmlFor="my-textfield">Hint text</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

}

now you can either create a Component (Wrapper) for an Input field. If you don't want to do that you can also auto init all of your components by adding:

```
// app.component.js    
import * as mdc from 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web';

    class App extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount(){        
            mdc.autoInit();
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div className="my-app">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            ); 
        }
    }
```

and add this to your textfields:

`<div className="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">`

Now the other possibility is to import like this:

`import {MDCCheckbox} from '@material/checkbox';`

Here you need to tell the bable-loader in your webpack config file to also include the node_modules/@material folder. Everything else stays basically the same.

Comment: The answer here is a very good however React have made changes to using the text refs and the method here is due to be deprecated. Please see the docs: [https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

The solution is to use a function to set the value to a property on the class, in this case this.refs.dialog would become this.dialog which is set as per the example below:

`code`
<aside ref={(dialog) => { this.dialog = dialog; }} />
`code`

Upvoted from me. Should be marked as the the correct answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @Jodo answer a little bit, this worked for me:

```
import React from 'react'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react'

import * as mdc from 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web'

@observer
export class RegisterForm extends React.Component{
    /**
     * Notice I'm calling mdc.autoInit() on the "RegisterForm" component NOT on any parent component
     * Actually, when I call mdc.autoInit() on any parent component, it won't work
     */
    componentDidMount=()=>{mdc.autoInit()}
    setMeta=(e)=>{
        this.props.store.storeReg.setMeta(e.target.name,e.target.value)
    }
    preview=()=>{
        this.props.store.storeReg.preview()
    }
    render=()=>{
        return(
            <form onChange={this.setMeta.bind(this)}>
                <div class="mdc-form-field">
                    <div class="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">
                        <input class="mdc-textfield__input" type="text" required name="email" value={this.props.store.storeReg.meta.get('email')}/>
                        <label class="mdc-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdc-form-field">
                    <div class="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">
                        <input class="mdc-textfield__input" type="text" required name="first_name" value={this.props.store.storeReg.meta.get('first_name')}/
                        <label class="mdc-textfield__label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdc-form-field">
                    <div class="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">
                        <input class="mdc-textfield__input" type="text" required name="last_name" value={this.props.store.storeReg.meta.get('last_name')}/>
                        <label class="mdc-textfield__label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--primary mdc-ripple-surface" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCRipple" type="button" onClic
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```